# PHP image scaling algorithm to fixed height and width confusion

Tags: php, algorithm

```
list($orig_width, $orig_height) = getimagesize($filename);

$width = $orig_width;
$height = $orig_height;

# taller
if ($height > $max_height) {
    $width = ($max_height / $height) * $width;
    $height = $max_height;
}

# wider
if ($width > $max_width) {
    $height = ($max_width / $width) * $height;
    $width = $max_width;
}
```

My confusion with the below algorithm is if, for example, we have an image that we want to downsize that has a resolution of 5600 * 1200 (Width = 5600, height = 1200) and we want to downsize it to say 560 * 460 (max-width = 560, max-height = 460) in this case max size is less than both sizes which condition will be applied. Which one will be taken and why check height before width.

Comment: These conditions are not _exclusive_ to begin with, so which ever applies, for the _current_ values of the checked variables, will apply. That could be one, none, or both.

Comment: This is something you could simply _test_ yourself, btw. Please do that in cases like this, before you come asking us.

Comment: add else if and else so you get onblock